# Unstable response time when use as web server

Tags: web-server

I want to use my Raspberry Pi 3B as web server but response times are very different and unstable , many of them are around 80ms to 160 ms but some of them go to 5000 ms to 20,000 ms !

```
OS : Linux raspberrypi 4.4.50-v7+ #970 SMP Mon Feb 20 19:18:29 GMT 2017 armv7l
WebServer : nginx/1.6.2 2017-04-20 12:44
PHP : 5.6.30-0+deb8u1
Opcache Enabled and it hits 100% of request after first request.
Opcache have Enough Memory.
opcache.max_accelerated_files = 20000
PHP Framework : Yii2 Basic
Query time : 4 ms and its Stable.
Yii Cache : ApcCache
I request raspberry over Lan with 2 ms stable latency.
CPU usage wont even go to 10%.
IOTop shows 500KB write with each Request , i dont think it will be a problem.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was with my SD card , it was class 10 but when i change SD card with another class 10 all my problem solved.